# ODE with parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let the following differential equation : where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g\in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R^n})$, with a parameter $p\in \mathbb{R}$ :
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot y_p(t)= g(t,y_p(t),p) & t\in[a,b]\\
y_p(a)=y_0\in \mathbb{R^n}
\end{cases}
$$
And I am looking for book/paper recommandations for this kind of systems with parameters :

For example can we prove that : $p\mapsto y(p,t):=y_p(t)$ is continuous for every $t$.

Comment: I would say that any course on the theory of ODEs should provide you with the answers you seek, see e.g. https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/555/555_notes/continuity.pdf

On your particular question, if $f$ is continuous wrt $t,y,p$, and Lipschitz in $y$ (with a constant independent of $t$ and $p$), then yes, $y_p$ is continuous wrt $p$ and $t$.